# Using decorator pattern to format table output

Tags: java, design-patterns, output, alignment, decorator

I have one specific problem. I have to make data output in console (as table) using Decorator pattern. I searched all over Google about decorator pattern, but I didn't find any similar example of using decorator pattern, so I decided to ask here.

So, I have to print data to console as table in which textual data is left aligned, and numbers are right aligned. I really don't have any idea how to do this by using decorator pattern, so I would be grateful if you could help. I have to do this in Java (in case that technology affect anything).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many choices when you decide to go with a design, but in this case I would create a class that writes to a cell the data and then 2 decorator for formatting. 
The sequence of operations would be: 
- set the value of the cell data from the first class; 
- set the formatting from the decorators; 
- write the data.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didn't mention that I have to use only System.out for printing table. So, I think that I should apply decorator pattern somewhere in formatting output string, but I don't have idea how to do that.